# Foreach not working in controller in Laravel

Tags: laravel-5

I want to export to excel datas from my table. So that i need to use foreach loop to get all the datas to form excel.

But foreach is not working in my controller but its working in view when i pass the variable and loop it.

My controller is:

```
$getAppProcess = ApplicationProcess::with('partner')->with('admin');
    $search = $request->q;
    if(isset($search)) {
        $getAppProcess->where(function ($query) use ($search){
            $query->where("application_id", "LIKE","%$search%")
            ->orWhere("applicant_name", "LIKE", "%$search%")
            ->orWhere("pan", "LIKE", "%$search%")
            ->orWhere("mobile", "LIKE", "%$search%");
        });
    }
    $getAppProcess->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();

    foreach ($getAppProcess as $value) {
        echo $value->pan;
    }
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not assigning any values, simply calling `$getAppProcess->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();` doesn't automatically populate `$getAppProcess` and make it iterable.

You need to do something like:

```
$result = $getAppProcess->orderBy('id', 'DESC')->get();
foreach($result as $value){
    echo($value->pan);
}
```